# How do you filter exact values from a php array

Tags: php

What's the best way to exclude an array of values from another array?  Like if I had a list of values I don't want in a different list?  I'm trying not to use reg ex and I don't think it should be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

> array_dif

For example like this

```
// our initial array
$arr = Array("blue", "green", "red", "yellow", "green", "orange", "yellow", "indigo", "red");
print_r($arr);

// remove the elements who's values are yellow or red
$arr = array_diff($arr, array("yellow", "red"));
print_r($arr);

// optionally you could reindex the array
$arr = array_values($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Ah, the indexes needs to be re-indexing after the process.  Thank you for that tid bit.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at PHP's [`array_diff()`-function](http://php.net/array_diff). Example from php.net:

```
// original list
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");

// these values will be removed from the first array
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");

$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

Comment: Now how would that return blau? Since when does array_diff translate English to German?

Comment: Thanks elusive,  I managed to figure it out awhile ago and I felt like a noob once I figured it was array_diff().